# Adding up numbers in single textbox and returning value to listbox using a method

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have the user enter in grades into a textbox like "94 85 46" and when they click the submit button, the numbers are taken from a Method. Inside of the method the numbers are individually multiplied by the percentage, and added together, the final value is listed in a listbox.

EX: "100 85 93" = (100 * .15)+(85 * .15) +(93 * .15) = 41.7

The problem that I am having is that I'm getting this error  **System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'** and it is pointing towards num
 It's telling me that the problem is.

```
quiz += space
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

My code is

```
Private Sub submitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click
    DisplayExamGrades() ' display grade for exams
    DisplayQuizGrades() ' display grade for quizzes
    DisplayAssignmentGrades() 'display grade for assignments
    DisplayAttendanceGrade() ' display grade for attendance
    DisplayFinalProjectGrade() 'display grade for final project


End Sub

'method for calculating quiz Grades
Sub DisplayQuizGrades()
    Dim a As String() = quizGradesTextBox.Text.Split(" "c)
    Dim quiz As Decimal
    For Each space As String In a
        quiz += space
        If quizGradesTextBox.Text.Length > 11 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter only 4 grades!")
        End If
        If quiz > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Individual grade numbers must be less than 100!")
        End If
        quiz *= 0.15
    Next
    resultListBox.Items.Add(quiz)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use the debugger to make sure that code does what you think/hope it does:  `For Each space As String In a`  Then if `space` is a string, then how can you add it to a decimal?  `quiz += space`  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well In regards to your question, the calculation, is trying to add a `String` type to a `Decimal` type. This string could be absolutely anything including letters and symbols. VB tries to do all its calculations using `Double` types. In this situtation, the error is saying that it's not valid to try an convert a string to a double. So, the code should be

```
quiz += CDec(space)
```

I also noticed that there are a few bits in your code that need tweaking. I've added the code below with a few inline comments. Hope it helps

```
Sub DisplayQuizGrades()
    Dim a As String() = quizGradesTextBox.Text.Split(" "c)
    Dim quiz As Decimal
    'The  check for number of grades entered shouldn't be just checking the length of the string
    'If a users enters 4 grades of 100 (unlikely i know), the length of the string will be 15
    'What you should really do, is check how many elements there are in the split array and 
    'make sure that they are all valid numbers before any calculactions are done on them.
    'If there is an error, exit this sub without adding anything to the list
    If a.Count > 4 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter only 4 grades!")
        'this is the line that you exit the sub if there are more than 4 grades
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each space As String In a
        If (Val(space) > 100) Or Val(space) <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Individual grade numbers must be greater than 0 and less than 100!")
            'this is the line that you exit the sub if there are invalid grades
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'here is the line that was causing you problems
        ' I have also moved it so that the number would only be added after the validation check
        quiz += CDec(Val(space)*.15)
    Next
    ' and would end up with completely the wrong result :-)
    resultListBox.Items.Add(quiz)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code worked, but there's another issue that I came across when running it. In the end result it adds up all of the numbers entered and multiplies them by .15, which gives "60", but i'm trying to figure out how to multiply the numbers individually and add the final value up. I do apologize, I see that I didn't make this fully understandable.

Comment: Wouldn't that give the same answer? Even so, see my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I divided the number of grades (2) by the percentage so that at most the percentage can only be 15

```
Sub DisplayQuizGrades()
    'take out the spaces in the string
    Dim a As String() = quizTextBox.Text.Split(" "c)
    Dim quiz As Decimal ' holds grade values

    'limit grades entered 
    If a.Count > 4 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Only 2 grades or less!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each space As String In a
        If (Val(space) > 100) Or Val(space) < 0 Then ' limit grades to be 0 - 100
            MessageBox.Show("Individual grade numbers must be greater than 0 and less than 100!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        quiz += CDec(space) ' add together numbers in textbox
    Next

    quiz = CDec(quiz * 0.0375) ' multiply added grades by percentage and divide by amount of numbers in text box
    resultListBox.Items.Add(quiz)
End Sub
```